# Add SSL Server Certificate for DB2 in JDBC code

Tags: jdbc, db2

I am trying to access a DB2 instance via SSL port.
I have the certificate that I need to access it.
But I am not sure of the parameter that I need to add it to so that connection is successful.

```
Dataset<Row> data=session.read().jdbc("jdbc:db2://url:port/DBNAME"+":sslConnection=true"        
    , "db2inst1.JOB_STATUS", connectionProperties);

    connectionProperties.put("driver", "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
    connectionProperties.put("url", "jdbc:db2://url:port/DBNAME");
    connectionProperties.put("user", "db2inst1");
    connectionProperties.put("password", "xxxxx");
```

The python code to connect to the same DB2 instance is this :

```
"DATABASE=DB_NAME;HOSTNAME=url;SSL=TRUE;PORT=port;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=xxxx;PWD=xxxx;SSLServerCertificate=DB2Certificate.arm;;SECURITY=SSL"
```

I would want to provide the DB2Certificate.arm as a parameter to the jdbc url , similar to the python parameter of SSLServerCertificate . How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following URL work for you?
`jdbc:db2://url:port/DBNAME:sslConnection=true;sslCertLocation=/full_path/DB2Certificate.arm;`

Comment: yes it worked with a slight modification, I had to provide the sslCertLocation as a connection properties

Answer (score 1):

Configuring your JRE/JVM to use SSL with Db2 for Linux/Unix/Windows is described [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_t0054066.html) and also [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_t0054065.html).

The exact version of your jdbc driver can also influence what configuration options exist (db2jcc4.jar, db2jcc.jar ).

Notice that configuring JRE is a different activity from configuring CLI programs (such as Python).

Suggest you try to follow the docs first.

Answer (score 0):

I can connect fine with `sslConnection=true;sslCertLocation=...` but for some reason (come on, IBM!) you need a semicolon after each value.

This works:
`jdbc:db2://192.168.1.69:50011/testdb:sslConnection=true;sslCertLocation=/tmp/db2.pem;`

This does NOT work (the only difference is the missing final semicolon):
`jdbc:db2://192.168.1.69:50011/testdb:sslConnection=true;sslCertLocation=/tmp/db2.pem`

I get the exception:
`com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: [jcc][10165][10051][4.32.28] Invalid database URL syntax: jdbc:db2://192.168.1.69:50011/testdb:sslConnection=true;sslCertLocation=/tmp/db2.pem. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815`

That's just silly... Anyway, there you go, put a semicolon at the end of each name=value;